# Set empty server timestamp and then give them a value, Is it possible on Angular firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, time

I want to declare two timestamps as 2 variables in order to get a starting date and an ending date. Through this i want to get the time when some things have been added to a collection and then to set the starting and ending time so i cal display all the elements that added between this time.

Is it possible to declare 2 timestamps as date or string global variables and then add them value when i want?

Example:

```
 <button class="btn add-sel" id="addSel" type="button" (click)="addSelected()">Add selected</button> 

<button class="btn add" id="add" type="button" (click)="onSubmit()">Start add</button>
```

Inside the onSubmit method i want to get the value to the first timestamp ex. startDate = new Date()

```
<button class="btn add-stop" id="stop" type="button" (click)="onSave()">Stop adding</button>
```

In onSave() method i want to get the endDate() = newDate() timestamp.

Comment: This needs some clarification. Where are you getting stuck? Yes, you should be able to have two different functions that can set a variable to a new Date object whenever they executed. Those functions are able to be executed by a button click? Where are you struggling?

Comment: I mean that i want to have 2 global timestamps, and i want the user to use start method in order to set the starting timestamp, then he will be able to select some items until he decides to stop this by click on a button to call endTime() method. In endTIme() i want to get the current ending timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the firestore timestamp when you create collection for the first time and then again update it or use another variable to set the ending timestamp.

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase';
```

// firestore timestamp

```
get timeStamp() {
  return firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

// set timestamp

```
createCollection() {
  collection.add({ ...data, whenCreated: this.timeStamp});
}
```

// update it or use another variable like whenModified

```
updateDocument() {
  doc.update({ ...data, whenModified: this.timeStamp });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I want to get the starting and ending timestamps through button click methods, and after that to get all the elements from firestore. The main thing is if i can declare 2 empty timestamps and give them a value when the method is called